# BSOD with uninstalled Malwarebytes (MBAMChameleon)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, malwarebytes

CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED during normal usage. I've noticed this same error in several times upon BSOD. Seems Windows is still requesting the application, despite being uninstalled; how do I uninstall Malwarebytes "completely" (make Win stop looking for it)?

[image]

Comment: Malwarebytes support is in a much better position to help you with this particular problem.  Have you contacted them to determine he reason their software is unable to start?   You have simply not provided enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhoud The reason's in the title; it shouldn't be trying to start at all. I did contact Malwarebytes, but unsure how long they'll take or what quality responses they give, so also giving a shot here.

Comment: Find and Delete the MBAMC Service Key (folder) in the windows registry.>>>HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services

Comment: @Moab The [entire folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTMuj.png) "MBAMChameleon"?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - I absolutely would not delete registry keys that belong to Malwarebytes without uninstalling Malwarebytes.  I can almost guarantee removing the registry keys as suggested manually will cause more problems then it will solve.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon yes but export it first so you will have a backup of what you deleted.

Comment: I would suggest to use: `sc.exe delete MBAMChameleon` from an admin prompt if you have run the uninstaller and this is all that remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I uninstall Malwarebytes "completely" (make Win stop looking for it)?

It appears that Malwarebytes was not uninstalled completely.  Luckily, Malwarebytes has a tool, to remove all Malwarebytes files previous configuration files from your system.

> The Malwarebytes Support Tool troubleshoots, repairs, and resolves
> issues with Malwarebytes for Windows. If you're experiencing a
> technical issue with Malwarebytes for Windows, you can use the
> Malwarebytes Support Tool to uninstall and reinstall Malwarebytes.
>
> The steps in this article detail the advanced Clean option. This
> option deletes all Malwarebytes for Windows files and all previous
> setting configurations. You then have the option to reinstall
> Malwarebytes for Windows with the default settings.

**You absolutely should not attempt to remove registry keys belonging to Malwarebytes yourself.** I suspect something prevented the successfully removal of Malwarebytes, best use the solution suggested by Malarebytes.  **There is a good chance you will leave cause your system to be unbootable if you attempt to remove the registry keys yourself.**

[Malwarebytes Support Tool.](https://downloads.malwarebytes.com/file/mbst)

Source: [Uninstall and reinstall Malwarebytes using the Malwarebytes Support Tool](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039023473-Uninstall-and-reinstall-Malwarebytes-using-the-Malwarebytes-Support-Tool)

Comment: Proceeded with the cleanup; if the error doesn't recur within a few days, I can conclude it worked. Though, unsure what worked exactly, as I also removed the registry key (I presume the cleanup would do it also?)

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon - You should be able to confirm if the problem has been solved by rebooting your system.

Comment: Rebooting the system doens't reproduce this issue, as it appears to be intermittent - regardless, I haven't seen it again since applying the fix, and have reinstalled Windows at this point.